# InitializationScript with -Credential

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, start-job

I have a problem with InitializationScript functions in start-job. I'm trying to call functions in cmd-let start-job, ***so as not to repeat them*** in scriptBlock of job it’s what I want. This’s basically code without try and catch and others.

```
$username = ******
$password = ******
$sec_password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $sec_password
$functions = {
    Function GenericSqlQuery
    {
        $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
        $Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
        $connection.Open()
        $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
        $Command.Connection = $Connection
        $Command.CommandText = "Select @@servername as name" <# for example #>
        $DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $Command
        $DataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600
        $Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
        [void]$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
        return $Dataset.tables[0]
    }
}
[Scriptblock]$Scriptblock = {
    GenericSqlQuery
}
Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -Credential $creds | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

 CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken
error: [localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: The stub received bad data.
```

I know you say your credentials are corrupt but my code works without -**InitializationScript** with $creds and no problem.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Does the `GenericSqlQuery` script work when you place it within the `$ScriptBlock`? What happens when you make the `GenericSqlQuery` function global: `Function Global:GenericSqlQuery`? I think you need to troubleshoot this a little deeper yourself by simplifying your script and confirm e.g. that you can call a (simple) function in the `-InitializationScript` from the `-ScriptBlock` at all...

Comment: about Function Global:GenericSqlQuery
A Windows PowerShell background job runs a command "in the background" without interacting with the current session.

Therefor, the current session scope is ignored.